# Pdo PASSWORD() function

Tags: php, pdo

sorry for my bad english.
my problem;

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user where id = ? and pass = PASSWORD(?)"); 
$query->execute(array($hes, $pass));  

if ($query){
echo "ok";}
else{
echo "empty";}
```

result:
if the password is correct = "ok"
if the password is not correct = "ok"
How do I fix it?

Comment: `if ($query){` means if the query has run correctly.... not whether it has returned a result or not.... you then need to count the number of results that have been returned using [rowCount()](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).... if that's 0, then "empty" else "ok"

Comment: i am a idiots :( i forgot. thank you

Comment: I appreciate this might fall under the "Oh, it's not used in any website - I'm just learning" banner but from the looks of this, you're storing the password in the database in plain text. Please, please, ***please*** do not do this. Have a look at a hashing framework and only compare hashes. This way if your database ever gets compromised, passwords aren't exposed. Aside from that, it's not good practise to store plaintext passwords anywhere really. Here's a link to PHPass: http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

Comment: @ScottMcGready He's not storing it in plain text. He's storing it in the hashed format that `PASSWORD()` returns.

Comment: @barmar Whoops, seems like I got tunnel vision, didn't seem to register with me on first glance. Still, I want to know what tutorial/book/website keeps recommending designing user/pass login systems as a good tutorial for beginners and fire them into oblivion.

Comment: yes, not plain text. using password() function @ScottMcGready

Answer (score 1):

You're only testing whether the query got an error or not, you're not testing whether it returned any rows. Use:

```
if ($query->fetch()) {
    echo "ok";
} else {
    echo "empty";
}
```

`fetch()` returns the next row of the results, which is the first (and presumably only) row in this case. If there's no next row, it returns `false`.